# What is a clean way to toggle a slide in menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so I am working on my new personal website and I have came to making the off canvas menu toggable. How cna I do so?

So far I have:

```js
var mainNav = document.getElementById('menu');
var navToggle = document.getElementById('menu-toggle');


mainNav.classList.add('collapsed');


function mainNavToggle() {
  mainNav.classList.toggle('collapsed');
}


navToggle.addEventListener('click', mainNavToggle);
```

```css
.collapsed {
  margin-left: -330px;
}
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 90px 0 0 30px;
}
.navigation li {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.navigation a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.navigation i {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navigation .double-line {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.45;
}
.navigation .double-line span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.clicked span {
  background-color: #000;
}
.menu-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.menu-toggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<button class="menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</button>

<nav class="navigation" role="navigation" id="menu">
  <ul>
    /* Menu contents */
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But with this code when the page loads you can see the menu being swept to the left, I dont want this.

How can I make my toggle button change colour when the menu is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the class `collapsed` to the nav and removing the initial toggle solves your blinking issue! And toggling an `active` class on the toggle gets you a grey toggle when the `$menu` is open! The `transition` CSS property is optional to make the bg transition from transparent to grey look smooth.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mbs1kymv/1/

JS:

```
var $menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var $toggle = document.getElementById('menu-toggle');

$toggle.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    $menu.classList.toggle('collapsed');
    $toggle.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navigation collapsed" role="navigation" id="menu"> ... </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-toggle {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
 }

.menu-toggle.active {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this has solved the blinking issue. Have you got anything for the second issue I stated? @gmustudent

Comment: @JackSewell Updated!

Comment: Thanks! @gmustudent